# Sorting array - child after its parent, but keep parents positions to each other

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got from database array like this (user select sorting by price):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 812
            [price] => 0
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 445
            [price] => 3400
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1102
            [price] => 3500
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 310
            [price] => 3700
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 311
            [price] => 3700
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 800
            [price] => 3900
            [par_id] => 310
        )
)
```

I need to sort this array to be items with **par_id == 0** and below them its children **child.par_id = parent.id** . To get array with these contidions I use function usort():

**usort($array, "cmp**");

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ( $a['id'] == $b['id'] ) {
    return 0;

  } else if ( $a['par_id'] ) {
    if ( $a['par_id'] == $b['par_id'] ) {
       return ( $a['id'] < $b['id'] ? -1 : 1 );
    } else {
      return ( $a['par_id'] >= $b['id'] ? 1 : -1 );
    }
  } else if ( $b['par_id'] ) {
    return ( $b['par_id'] >= $a['id'] ? -1 : 1);
  } else {
    return ( $a['id'] < $b['id'] ? -1 : 1 );
  }
}
```

It works and then I get array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 310
            [price] => 3700
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 311
            [price] => 3700
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 800
            [price] => 3900
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 812
            [price] => 0
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 445
            [price] => 3400
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1102
            [price] => 3500
            [par_id] => 0
        )
)
```

BUT, this array is not sorted by price. My question is, if it's possible to sort array in the state above, but also keep sorting by price, at least at parent (ideal case at child too). So the result array I would like to get is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 445
            [price] => 3400
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1102
            [price] => 3500
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 310
            [price] => 3700
            [par_id] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 812
            [price] => 0
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 311
            [price] => 3700
            [par_id] => 310
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 800
            [price] => 3900
            [par_id] => 310
        )
)
```

Parent first, immediately after them its child AND still sorted by price, which user selected.

Comment: you'd better use multi-array to do this and that would be much more clear.

Comment: do you only get the child items of one parent?

Comment: no, there can be more parents with more child items, but it's only one-level structure. Child can not have another child and every child has only one parent.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. You don't compare the prices in your `cmp` function, so it is a logical, that the resulting list is not sorted by price. Take a look at the following `cmp` function:

```php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['id'] === $b['id']) {
        return 0;
    }

    // both are child or both are parents, so compare by price
    $comparePrices = ($a['par_id'] && $b['par_id'])
        || (!$a['par_id'] && !$b['par_id']);

    $priceResult = $a['price'] > $b['price'] ? 1 : -1;

    if ($comparePrices) {
        return $priceResult;
    } else if ($a['par_id']) {
        // a is a child, so check if b is the parent
        return $a['par_id'] === $b['id'] ? 1 : $priceResult;
    } else if ($b['par_id']) {
        // b is a child, so check if a is the parent
        return $b['par_id'] === $a['id'] ? -1 : $priceResult;
    }
}
```

This should work, but no guarantee that it works for all cases.

For readabilities sake, you should implement this different anyways. Split your query into two. The first fetches all parents and orders by price, the second fetches all childs and orders by parent id and then by price. The merge operation of those arrays is a simple combination of `foreach` and `array_map`. For example:

```
$childItemsByParentId = [];
foreach ($childItems as $childItem) {
    $childItemsByParentId[$childItem['par_id']][] = $childItem;
}

$parentItems = array_map(function ($parentItem) use ($childItemsByParentId) {
    $childs = isset($childItemsByParentId[$parentItem['id']])
        ? $childItemsByParentId[$parentItem['id']]
        : [];

    $parentItem['childs'] = $childs;
    return $parentItem;
}, $parentItems);
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe the cmp function should be fine for now, but in my case can user select different column to sorting. How can I add third parameter to cmd function - name of column to sorting. And more, the fourth parameter should tell, if the sorting is ASC or DESC. Is it possible?

Comment: Google just told me, that another parameters can be added in global variables, right? So the last I would need, is oportunity to sorting even DESC. The function above sort always ASC.

Comment: I tryied your second suggestion with array_map(), but that is not excactly what I need. System, unfortunately, needs data in single level, so childs must be on the same level as its parents.

It looks the sorting cmp function you wrote works in around half cases. It is because it's impossible handle all cases or could be improved?

Comment: If you want to use the `cmp` function with dynamic sorting columns/directions, you have to create a factory, which will then create closures with the specified sorting column/direction algorithm. But this would really be a mess. You should stick to my second suggestion. It is not that hard, to create a flat array from those two queries.

Comment: Could you provide the dataset, with which the `cmp` function produces wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

I invent another way how to do it finally.

It goes through whole array and finds out if actual item is parent or child. If it is child, it goes through array again to find its parent. If parent is finded, it moves all items between child and parent position forward or backward (depends where child is - if in front of parent or after it) to make a space in array, where will be child placed.

```
$last_id = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
      $item = $data[$i];

      if ($item['par_id'] == 0) {
        $last_id = $item['id'];
        continue;
      }
      if ($last_id == $item['par_id']) {
        continue;
      }

      foreach($data as $d => $dat) {
        if ($item['par_id'] == $dat['id']) {

          if ($i < $d) {
            for($j = $i; $j < $d; $j++) { $data[$j] = $data[$j + 1]; }
            $empty = $d;
            $i -= 1;
          } else {
            for($j = $i; $j > $d; $j--) { $data[$j] = $data[$j - 1]; }
            $empty = $d + 1;
          }

          $data = $item;
    } } }
```